# MySQL Workbench: how do I set up "ON UPDATE" and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, utc, mysql-workbench

SEE: [Update timestamp column in Application or Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291104/update-timestamp-column-in-application-or-database)

I'm trying to model something similar in Workbench, but I don't know where to set the "ON UPDATE" part. The best I can get is the following:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `foo`.`test`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo`.`test` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo`.`test` (
  `test_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `date_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Where do I go in Workbench to set up this ON UPDATE part?

Also, I have a rule that all timestamps stored in the database should be UTC. How do I make CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOW, etc. be UTC?

Comment: For anyone interested, I created a [Workbench script](https://gist.github.com/pepijnolivier/61ba3d69af2884ef2d6fa107d657e2d5) that automatically adds the timestamp columns on all tables -except pivot tables

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.35. Open create/alter table panel, switch to the columns tab, right click on the timestamp field; there you can see possible `default` and `on update` options.

Important note: You can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default or updated value for only a single column in a table!

[image: Sample screenshot showing the context menu]

Regarding the UTC question, you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947299/how-do-i-make-mysqls-now-and-curdate-functions-use-utc). There is an accepted solution there.

I would suggest you to read MySQL reference manuals as well for [Timestamp data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) and [`NOW()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Comment: OK, that worked for me. If I wanted to know when a record was soft deleted, I would just create a date_deleted and set that from the application layer, right? Also, any idea about the UTC issue?

Comment: yes, if you are already running a query to mark an item as soft deleted, then it's better to update the date from the application layer as well within the same query (or at least same transaction). I updated the answer for UTC issue.

Comment: @carbonr Did you read the "important note" on the answer, is that what you ask or do you ask something else?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worked for me

Comment: A small addendum: For me, I had to specify Not Null `NN` before it would auto update from the UI (Workbench 6.0.8)

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I do with MySQL Workbench

Data Type: TIMESTAMP
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score -2):

By default MySQL sets the first `timestamp` field to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on every `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement. I go about designing my schema in a way so that `updated_at` is first `timestamp` field, so that I don't have to explicitly specify it.